# Adding fontawesome to shortcodes ultimate tab

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-awesome

I'd like to add a fontawesome icon to a shortcodes ultimate tab title.

When I try to do it inline

```
<i class="fa fa-500px"></i>
```

nothing comes up. Is it possible, either using CSS or some other means?

[font-awesome-icon] Tab text 1

[font-awesome-icon] Tab text 2

[font-awesome-icon] Tab text 3

Comment: You need to link the font awesome css and their fonts or use a CDN

Answer (score 2):

For using shortcodes, there is a plugin which fetches the latest font awesome icons:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-font-awesome/

It works like this:

```
[icon name="fa-flag" class="fa-2x fa-spin fa-border"]
```

[image: Plugin's Demo]

They have also alternatives syntaxes for previous versions (with the `icon-` class names).